# Heroku clock process not storing data to a CSV file

Tags: python, heroku, clock

I am using Heroku to make a webpage that daily scrapes some content from other pages and afterwards shows this on the page. The problem I encountered is that when running the daily `Clock.py` file that the scraping process is executed but the new CSV file is not stored at all. What do you think is the reason for this?

To provide some further information, the scraper function opens a webpage, scrapes some content and returns a pandas dataframe. What I now want to achieve is to store this dataframe to a folder `data/` with the name `df_result2.csv`. A short remark: The scraping process works perfectly, as I could print the dataframe to the console after each run. The only problem comes from storing this file. Do you have any suggestions what I should change?

```
#clock.py
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
import datetime
import pandas as pd

from components import scraper

sched = BlockingScheduler()

#Example for a job
@sched.scheduled_job('interval', minutes=3)
def timed_job():
    print('This job is run every 3 minutes.')
    result = scraper()
    pd.DataFrame.to_csv(result, "data/df_result2.csv")
    print(result)
```

Comment: I think what you're looking for is result.to_csv("data/df_result2.csv") since pd.DataFrame.to_csv is an instance bnot static method of the pd.DataFrame class as far as I know. What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: @DavidWaterworth Thank you for your reply. Interestingly there is no error message at all.  The reason might be due to this euphemeral filesystem as Chris explained. The file may hence not be available to other dynos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem is probably that the `data/` directory doesn't exist.

But the *bigger* problem is that Heroku's filesystem [is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Any changes you make to it will be lost whenever your dyno restarts. This happens frequently and unpredictably ([at least once per day](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts)).

Since you're generating your data every three minutes the risk is somewhat limited, but there could definitely be times that that file might not exist when you need it.

Instead of storing your data on the filesystem I strongly suggest that you use a proper [data store](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores). PostgreSQL works great with Heroku. If you really want to use a file, consider [storing it on a third-party service like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).